# Python SQLAlchemy - Cannot Access Primary Key Column of SELECT Statement's Result

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
s = select([stations.c.name]).where(stations.c.name == station_name)
stations = connection.execute(s).fetchone()
```

I have the above code to run SELECT on a SQL table. However, while other columns of the matched entry were accessible, trying to access its primary key column by stations['id'] gives the error:

```
"Could not locate column in row for column 'id'"
```

Why is that?

Table definition:

```
stations = Table('stations', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True),
        Column('name', String(16), nullable = False)
        )
```

Comment: please, provide us your [`Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) object definition

Comment: Here, just added it.

Comment: which [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQLite

Comment: was answer helpful or there are some problems?

Comment: yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: you should avoid giving the same name to different objects because in your case after statement

```
 stations = connection.execute(s).fetchone()
```

initial `stations` [`Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) object is no longer accessible. You can rename fetched object to `station_record`, or rename `stations` `Table` object to `stations_table`, or both.

---

## Answer

If you want to get `id` of a record – than you should query it:

```
s = select([stations.c.id, stations.c.name]).where(stations.c.name == station_name)
```

or

```
s = select(stations.columns).where(stations.c.name == station_name)
```

Finally we can have something like

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String, create_engine, select

db_uri = 'sqlite://'
engine = create_engine(db_uri)
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
stations = Table('stations', metadata,
                 Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                 Column('name', String(16), nullable=False)
                 )
stations.create(checkfirst=True)
connection = engine.connect()
station_name = 'sample text'
connection.execute(stations.insert().values(name=station_name))
s = select(stations.columns).where(stations.c.name == station_name)
station_record = connection.execute(s).fetchone()
station_record_id = station_record['id']
station_record_name = station_record['name']
```

Comment: Running stations['id'] still gives the same error(but stations['name']  doesn't). Do you know why the primary key column is not accessible?

Comment: @StephenChen: fixed answer